# Ext.Msg.show in ajax not append the page

Tags: ajax, extjs

I have a function for saving data. Before saving data there is dialog confirmation Yes or No. While I click option Yes the page behind this is back to the gridview (it's list). What i want is while click Yes the page behind is not change.

This is my function :

```
function SaveData(StatusSubmit) {
        var d = ControlToData();
        if (state == FormState.ADD) {
            ShowLoading("sa-body", "Updating data .. Please Wait ...");
            $.ajax({
                url: root + "PF/Add?status=" + StatusSubmit,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(d),
                success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                    storePF.add(
                        {
                            PFID: result.PF.PFID
                        , Title: result.PF.Title
                        });

                    ChangeFormState(FormState.VIEW);
                    tabs.setActiveTab('pageGrid');

                    if (result.ErrorMail.length > 0) {
                        alert("Error while sending email !\nError description : " + result.ErrorMail + "\nPlease contact your System Administrator !");
                    }

                    if (result.Error.length > 0) {
                        var str = "<br/><br/><span style='color:red;font-weight:bold'>Success add new PF !</span>";
                        MsgBox2("Budget Validation", result.Error + str);
                    }
                    else
                        MsgBox("Success add new PF !");
                },
                complete: function () {
                    HideLoading();
                }
            });
        } 
    }
```

I add new dialog confirmation like this, but it does not work (didn't append the page after click Yes button):

```
function SaveData(StatusSubmit) {
        var d = ControlToData();
        if (state == FormState.ADD) {
            ShowLoading("sa-body", "Updating data .. Please Wait ...");
            $.ajax({
                url: root + "PF/Add?status=" + StatusSubmit,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(d),
                success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                    storePF.add(
                        {
                            PFID: result.PF.PFID
                        , Title: result.PF.Title
                        });

                    ChangeFormState(FormState.VIEW);
                    tabs.setActiveTab('pageGrid');

                    if (result.ErrorMail.length > 0) {
                        alert("Error while sending email !\nError description : " + result.ErrorMail + "\nPlease contact your System Administrator !");
                    }

                    if (result.Error.length > 0) {
                              $.post(root + "PF/GetSetupName", function (datas) {
                        if (datas == "FILTER_BRAND") {
                            Ext.Msg.show({
                                title: 'Over Budget',
                                msg: 'Budget is over. Modify or Not ?',
                                fn: function (btn) {
                                    if (btn == "yes") {
                                        SaveData("none");
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        CancelData();
                                    }
                                },
                                buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
                                icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    }
                    else
                        MsgBox("Success add new PF !");
                },
                complete: function () {
                    HideLoading();
                }
            });
        } 
    }
```

I try also separate this Ext.Msg.show in another function. but it doesn't work. Is there any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that when I try to do a mask and an ajax request at the same time, Ext gets overwhelmed and will not properly display the mask.

To fix this, I delay doing my ajax request until Ext & the browser have had enough time to properly display the mask. It generally does not need much time.  In the example below, it waits 50 ms before posting.

```
Ext.get(document.body).mask("Updating data .. Please Wait ...", 'x-mask-loading');

Ext.defer(function() {
    Ext.Ajax.request({ ... });
}, 50);
```

This gives the browser enough time to render the masking before it has to do anything else.